# How to assign value to a struct member of a struct?

Tags: c, struct, nested

I am learning about nested structs in C, and what I want to do is to be able to assign a value to my struct's member struct. I'm having trouble figuring this out, and I don't want to force myself to initialize the member struct in the initialization of the struct. Why do I keep getting an error when I try to compile this code?

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:16:23: error: expected expression before '{' token
  fooPerson.fullname = {"Foo", 'B', "Baz"};
```

```
#define LEN 20

struct names {
    char first[LEN];
    char middle;
    char last[LEN];
};

struct person {
    struct names fullname;
};

int main() {
    struct person fooPerson;
    fooPerson.fullname = {"Foo", 'B', "Baz"};

    // NOT this: it works, but not the solution I'm asking for
    // struct person fooPerson = {{"Foo", 'B', "Baz"}};
}
```

Comment: You can only initialize something once. And arrays are not assignable.

Comment: Right, I edited the title to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting in C99, you can use a compound literal for this:

```
fooPerson.fullname = (struct names){ "Foo", 'B', "Baz" };
```

If you’re stuck with C89, though, you’re mostly out of luck, unless you want to do something like this:

```
{
    struct names n = { "Foo", 'B', "Baz" };
    fooPerson.fullname = n;
}
```

Felix points out in the comments that neither of these are truly *initialization*—it’s only initialization when it happens as part of the declaration, which isn’t the case here. Rather, both are assignments. Still, this ought to do what you want.

Comment: dropping my answer for this, but please add it's not *initialization*, because initialization happens (by definition) in the declaration.

Comment: Yes please point out that none of this is initialization, as the OP is confused about the term. Also in C89, nothing is stopping you from declaring a second struct variable, initialize it and copy it in runtime. Which is what this code is doing. `fooPerson = n;` would work perfectly fine in C89, no need for memcpy as there are no pointers here.

Comment: @Lundin: I’m not sure what I was thinking with the `memcpy`. In any case, I edited it to be a normal assignment.

Comment: @icktoofay I mainly wanted to point out that there's no notable difference between C99 and C90 for this example. Either allow you to create a temporary object and do runtime assignment.

Answer (score 1):

*Initialization* is the term for giving a variable a value upon declaration. Everything else is *assignment*.

Thus if you *initialize* your variable, and only then, you can use an *initializer list* (the `{ }`).

```
struct person fooPerson = { {"Foo", 'B', "Baz"} };
```

Alternatively you can use designated initializers:

```
struct person fooPerson =
{
  .fullname = 
  { 
    .first  = "Foo",
    .middle = 'B',
    .last   = "Baz"
  }
};
```